# WordPress JavaScript import error Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Before posting a new question, I already explored the existing question on Stack Overflow but unfortunately they didn't work.

So I'm getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error, the question that I reviewed tell to use `type=module` in script tag or use any `Babel` tool etc.

But the main thing is I'm using this in my `WordPress` project and for the reason above methods doesn't work in my case. Here is my file in which I'm trying to import `jquery` but getting the import error.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
class Search {
    constructor() {
            console.log('Custom constructor called');
            this.openButton = $(".js-searh-trigger");
            this.closeButton = $(".js-search-overlay__close");
            this.searchOverlay = $(".search-overlay");
            this.events();
        }
        // 2. Evetns
    events() {
            this.openButton.on('click', this.openOverlay)
            this.closeButton.on('click', this.closeOverlay)
        }
        // 3. Methods
    openOverlay() {
        this.searchOverlay.addClass('search-overlay--active')
    }
    closeOverlay() {
        this.searchOverlay.removeClass('search-overlay--active')
    }
}
export default Search;
alert('search js working')
console.log(
    'custom working'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you're using it on the client side? In that case, you should load jQuery using a script tag, rather than use import. E.g:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: no, although it can be added like this, but by doing so I won't be able to access jquery functions in my `js` file

Comment: Is it client side or server side?